# Tautological bundle transition functions

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I wanted to construct transition functions for the tautological bundles on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and $\mathbb{C}P^n$, but I guess I have not understood the concept of tautological bundle well enough.

Can someone clarify, and give hints for the question?

All I know is that the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is given by the projection $\pi$

$\pi: E=\{(L,v) \in \mathbb{R}P^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : v \in L \} \to \mathbb{R}P^n $.

Comment: Good hints/clarifications/answers will depend on what you already know. Please include this information in your question: for instance, what is your definition of the tautological line bundle?

Comment: I've edited and put the definition that I know.

Comment: Now, edit with the trivializations on the standard open sets $U_i = \{[x]\in\Bbb RP^n: x_i\ne 0\}$.